# Why do we use XStream annotations in Optaplanner

Tags: java, xstream, optaplanner

I am new to OptaPlanner and trying to understand the code and I observed below annotations being used in many places in the code but I don't think we are using serialization anywhere in our project. 
Could someone explain when, on what classes, and why do we use below annotations in optaplanner

@XStreamAlias
@XStreamInclude
@XStreamConverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the examples UI that read/writes to XML, it's not related to optaplanner-core at all. If you read/write to JSON (jackson) or a database (JPA/hibernate), you'd delete those.

To see what they do, go to the XStream website and see the "annotations" page.

Comment: Thanks much. Is there anyway I can pass all rule validations if certain condition is true?
My use case is to pass all the constraint validations and do nothing if my input data matches certain criteria?